# Getting Permanent ManagedObjectIDs for Use with UILocalNotifications

Tags: ios, core-data, uilocalnotification

I am looking for some advice.

I am using CoreData with NSFetchedResultsController to track changes in the data model.  When the data model changes, I use the fetchedResultsController notification to check to see if any UILocalNotifications needs to be created, deleted, or updated.

To correlate the CoreData items with UILocalNotifications items, I add an ID into each UILocalNotification.  Since UILocalNotifications can last past the execution of the app, I an using the objectID `[t.objectID URIRepresentation]` as the key.

Ok, so this mostly works, but the problem I have is that when I create a new object and save it, I get a call back in the NSFetchedResultsController that the item has been created WHILE the objectID is still temporary.  The next time I hear about that object, the objectID is now permanent and it does not correlate with the original (temporary) ID.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?  What other ID could I use?  How do I get a notification that has a permanent ID at the call to NSFetchedResultsController?

Answer (score 4):

A permanent NSManagedObjectID identifies a managed object as residing in a particular persistent store. Therefore, an objectID can't be permanent until the object is saved to a store.

You can use:

```
[NSManagedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:]
```

…to force IDs to permanent but the method does have side effect similar to a save e.g. empty required properties can generate errors.

Of course, the simplest solution is to just save the managed objects before you get their objectIDs. If you want any external object to refer to them, you need to do that anyway.

Comment: *side effect similar to a save e.g. empty required properties can generate errors* -- Another reason why I *always* set *all* of my managed object properties to be *optional*   :)